# How to loop through json obejct and return keys and values if they are all different or even null? Vue, Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, object, bootstrap-vue

need to go through a JSON object which might or might not have properties fields it can be null or it can have 10 different ones I then need to print it in a code block, the JSON data is here:

```
 "grade": [
        {
            "alias": "G1",
            "id": "4d72868e-c46f-41d1-83a6-429a2421fd34",
            "name": "Grade 1",
            "properties": {
                "size": "A1",
                "dimensions": "2x2",
                "maturity_weight": "150"
            },
            "createdAt": "2020-03-30T09:57:24.756Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-30T09:57:24.756Z",
            "farmId": "703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"
        },
        {
            "alias": "G2",
            "id": "62fbefef-3342-43aa-8ed3-ed2ff0ff7cd6",
            "name": "Grade 2",
            "properties": {
                "size": "A2",
                "dimensions": "3x3",
                "maturity_weight": "150"
            },
            "createdAt": "2020-11-22T13:29:42.461Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-11-22T13:29:42.461Z",
            "farmId": "703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"
        },
        {
            "alias": "G3",
            "id": "9ce20ee1-c197-4775-97cb-35998ce51d4b",
            "name": "Grade 3",
            "properties": {
                "size": "A3",
                "dimensions": "4x4",
                "maturity_weight": "150"
            },
            "createdAt": "2020-11-22T13:31:16.955Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-11-22T13:31:16.955Z",
            "farmId": "703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"
        },
        {
            "alias": "G4",
            "id": "83f6ff4b-ab75-4930-ab84-59763b24d435",
            "name": "Grade 4",
            "properties": {
                "size": "A4",
                "dimensions": "4x4",
                "maturity_weight": "150"
            },
            "createdAt": "2020-11-22T13:31:16.955Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-11-22T13:31:16.955Z",
            "farmId": "703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"
        },
        {
            "alias": "G5",
            "id": "8dea25be-93e3-4ab4-ae58-685e4ab05dbf",
            "name": "Grade 5",
            "properties": {
                "units": "gms",
                "maxWeight": "170",
                "minWeight": "100"
            },
            "createdAt": "2020-08-11T08:52:23.484Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-11T08:52:23.484Z",
            "farmId": "703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"
        },
        {
            "alias": "G6",
            "id": "85aa81e4-b428-44d5-9ee2-4215de6c8226",
            "name": "Grade 6",
            "properties": null,
            "createdAt": "2020-05-15T09:53:23.809Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-15T09:53:23.809Z",
            "farmId": "703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"
        },
        {
            "alias": "SG",
            "id": "f4cd4ec4-1b99-42b1-839b-cd18c54d1761",
            "name": "some grade",
            "properties": {
                "shape": "",
                "units": "gms",
                "dimension": "",
                "maxWeight": "2",
                "minWeight": "1"
            },
            "createdAt": "2021-06-11T15:10:39.102Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-06-11T15:10:39.102Z",
            "farmId": "703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"
        },
        {
            "alias": "SO",
            "id": "ef862161-e3e9-4b84-9164-178a600a15a8",
            "name": "som",
            "properties": {
                "shape": null,
                "units": "gms",
                "dimension": null,
                "maxWeight": "3",
                "minWeight": "2"
            },
            "createdAt": "2021-06-11T15:18:16.460Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-06-11T15:18:16.460Z",
            "farmId": "703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"
        },
        {
            "alias": "AS",
            "id": "4a4e1584-b0a7-4069-8851-0ee7f9e18267",
            "name": "asdfadf",
            "properties": {
                "shape": null,
                "units": "gms",
                "dimension": null,
                "maxWeight": "sdf",
                "minWeight": "asfd"
            },
            "createdAt": "2021-06-11T15:19:07.387Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-06-11T15:19:07.387Z",
            "farmId": "703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"
        }
    ]
}
```

And return values such as:

```
<br>
    <b-row>
    <b-col class="underline">My Grades</b-col>
    </b-row>
    <br>
    <div v-if="grades.length > 0">
    <b-card-group class="mb-4" v-for="grade in grades" :key="grade.id">
      <b-card :title="getTitle(grade)">
        <b-card-text class="list-card">
        

           
          {{getProperties(grade)}}
        
    

          <span style="float:right">
            <b-button
              class="mr-1"
              v-b-modal.modalConfirmDelete
              type="submit"
              variant="primary"
              size="sm"
            >
              <b-icon icon="map" size="is-small"></b-icon>
            </b-button>
            <b-button
              class="mr-1"
              type="reset"
              variant="danger"
              @click="actionDelete(grade.id)" 
              size="sm"
            >
              <b-icon icon="trash-fill" size="is-small"></b-icon>
            </b-button>
            <b-modal id="modalConfirmDelete" title="BootstrapVue">
                ddd
            </b-modal>
          </span>
        </b-card-text>
      </b-card>
    </b-card-group>
```

i tried a few things like map, this below and join and nothing works because the properties in the json are all diff, tried for loop with length too.

```
getProperties(grade) {
      if (grade) {
         for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(grade)) {
            return `key: ${key}, value: ${value}`
          }
          
         }
      }
    },
```

Only need properties, thanks in advance

Comment: Please can you clarify, what is your *desired output* for the `getProperties` function? Do you want the `properties` property from each of the entries in `grade` ? What format do you want it in?

Comment: sorry yea i just need it for one grade, but it would cycle through all the properties that arent null and the output would be a string such as: Weight: 20, MaxDimension: 30, Extra: blablablabla, so whatever is in the properties of a single grade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is *this* what you're looking for?

```js
var jsonData = JSON.parse('{"grade":[{"alias":"G1","id":"4d72868e-c46f-41d1-83a6-429a2421fd34","name":"Grade 1","properties":{"size":"A1","dimensions":"2x2","maturity_weight":"150"},"createdAt":"2020-03-30T09:57:24.756Z","updatedAt":"2020-03-30T09:57:24.756Z","farmId":"703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"},{"alias":"G2","id":"62fbefef-3342-43aa-8ed3-ed2ff0ff7cd6","name":"Grade 2","properties":{"size":"A2","dimensions":"3x3","maturity_weight":"150"},"createdAt":"2020-11-22T13:29:42.461Z","updatedAt":"2020-11-22T13:29:42.461Z","farmId":"703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"},{"alias":"G3","id":"9ce20ee1-c197-4775-97cb-35998ce51d4b","name":"Grade 3","properties":{"size":"A3","dimensions":"4x4","maturity_weight":"150"},"createdAt":"2020-11-22T13:31:16.955Z","updatedAt":"2020-11-22T13:31:16.955Z","farmId":"703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"},{"alias":"G4","id":"83f6ff4b-ab75-4930-ab84-59763b24d435","name":"Grade 4","properties":{"size":"A4","dimensions":"4x4","maturity_weight":"150"},"createdAt":"2020-11-22T13:31:16.955Z","updatedAt":"2020-11-22T13:31:16.955Z","farmId":"703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"},{"alias":"G5","id":"8dea25be-93e3-4ab4-ae58-685e4ab05dbf","name":"Grade 5","properties":{"units":"gms","maxWeight":"170","minWeight":"100"},"createdAt":"2020-08-11T08:52:23.484Z","updatedAt":"2020-08-11T08:52:23.484Z","farmId":"703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"},{"alias":"G6","id":"85aa81e4-b428-44d5-9ee2-4215de6c8226","name":"Grade 6","properties":null,"createdAt":"2020-05-15T09:53:23.809Z","updatedAt":"2020-05-15T09:53:23.809Z","farmId":"703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"},{"alias":"SG","id":"f4cd4ec4-1b99-42b1-839b-cd18c54d1761","name":"some grade","properties":{"shape":"","units":"gms","dimension":"","maxWeight":"2","minWeight":"1"},"createdAt":"2021-06-11T15:10:39.102Z","updatedAt":"2021-06-11T15:10:39.102Z","farmId":"703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"},{"alias":"SO","id":"ef862161-e3e9-4b84-9164-178a600a15a8","name":"som","properties":{"shape":null,"units":"gms","dimension":null,"maxWeight":"3","minWeight":"2"},"createdAt":"2021-06-11T15:18:16.460Z","updatedAt":"2021-06-11T15:18:16.460Z","farmId":"703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"},{"alias":"AS","id":"4a4e1584-b0a7-4069-8851-0ee7f9e18267","name":"asdfadf","properties":{"shape":null,"units":"gms","dimension":null,"maxWeight":"sdf","minWeight":"asfd"},"createdAt":"2021-06-11T15:19:07.387Z","updatedAt":"2021-06-11T15:19:07.387Z","farmId":"703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"}]}');

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() { return {
      grades: jsonData.grade,
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" /><script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js"></script><script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script><script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-row>
    <b-col class="underline">My Grades</b-col>
  </b-row>
  <br>
  <div v-if="grades.length > 0">
    <b-card-group class="mb-4" v-for="grade in grades" :key="grade.id">
      <b-card :title="grade.name">
        <b-card-text v-for="[key, value] in Object.entries(grade.properties != null ? grade.properties : {})" :key="key" class="list-card">
          {{ `${key}: ${value}` }}
          <span style="float:right">
              <b-button
                class="mr-1"
                v-b-modal.modalConfirmDelete
                type="submit"
                variant="primary"
                size="sm"
              >
                <b-icon icon="map" size="is-small"></b-icon>
              </b-button>
              <b-button
                class="mr-1"
                type="reset"
                variant="danger"
                @click="actionDelete(grade.id)" 
                size="sm"
              >
                <b-icon icon="trash-fill" size="is-small"></b-icon>
              </b-button>
              <b-modal id="modalConfirmDelete" title="BootstrapVue">
                  ddd
              </b-modal>
            </span>
        </b-card-text>
      </b-card>
    </b-card-group>
  </div>
</div>
```

The main change I made was to replace `getProperties` with a `v-for`, since displaying multiple rows in the table requires a new HTML element for each property in `grade.properties`.

For that `v-for`, I'm looping on `Object.entries(grade.properties ?? {})`.

- [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will return a `[key, value]` array for each property in an object, allowing us to easily display both.
- [`grade.properties ?? {}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) just returns an empty object `{}` when `grade.properties` is `null` or `undefined`. This avoids giving nullish values to `Object.entries()`, which throws an error if you call it with `null`/ `undefined`.

  - If the `??` operator isn't supported in your setup, then this will suffice just as well:
    `grade.properties != null ? grade.properties : {}`

(I also replaced `getTitle(grade)` with `grade.name` directly, but that's more a matter of preference.)

Comment: Amazing stuff! Thanks will try now! Great explanation :)

Comment: invalid expression: Unexpected token '?' in

    Object.entries(grade.properties ?? {})

  Raw expression: v-for="[key, value] in Object.entries(grade.properties ?? {})"


  105|    <b-card-group class="mb-4" v-for="grade in grades" :key="grade.id">
  106|      <b-card :title="getTitle(grade)">
  107|        <b-card-text v-for="[key, value] in Object.entries(grade.properties ?? {})" :key="key" class="list-card">
     |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  108|          {{ `${key}: ${value}` }}
  109|          <span style="float:right"

Comment: Getting an error. For the question marks, I don't know if it eslint or, it says emitted value instead of an instance error

Comment: The json data is in my data as grades[] so I have it in an array of objects and its filling it from postgres

Comment: It doesn't like the `??` op, that's a newer JS feature. Let me sub it out.

Comment: thanks a million, will have a check now, someone answered in the previous qs I posted and it seems to work now but I need to tweak it so will check yours too it could be more dynamic! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have trouble working out what you want from the `getProperties` function, but does this help?

```js
const grade1 = {"alias": "G1","id": "4d72868e-c46f-41d1-83a6-429a2421fd34","name": "Grade 1","properties": {"size": "A1","dimensions": "2x2","maturity_weight": "150"},"createdAt": "2020-03-30T09:57:24.756Z","updatedAt": "2020-03-30T09:57:24.756Z","farmId": "703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"};
const grade2 = {"alias": "G6","id": "85aa81e4-b428-44d5-9ee2-4215de6c8226","name": "Grade 6","properties": null,"createdAt": "2020-05-15T09:53:23.809Z","updatedAt": "2020-05-15T09:53:23.809Z","farmId": "703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"};
const grade3 = {"alias": "SG","id": "f4cd4ec4-1b99-42b1-839b-cd18c54d1761","name": "some grade","properties": {"shape": "","units": "gms","dimension": "","maxWeight": "2","minWeight": "1"},"createdAt": "2021-06-11T15:10:39.102Z","updatedAt": "2021-06-11T15:10:39.102Z","farmId": "703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"};
const grade4 = {"alias": "SO","id": "ef862161-e3e9-4b84-9164-178a600a15a8","name": "som","properties": {"shape": null,"units": "gms","dimension": null,"maxWeight": "3","minWeight": "2"},"createdAt": "2021-06-11T15:18:16.460Z","updatedAt": "2021-06-11T15:18:16.460Z","farmId": "703ab269-20f5-4dca-8687-e14de5f6a4cb"};

// this function is used in getProperties
function keyValString(obj) {
  // reduce the output to one string
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((str, [key, value], index) => { // for each key and value
    if (value) { // if value is not null or an empty string
      if (str) str += ", "; // if there is already text, add a comma and space
      str += `${key}: ${value}`; // add on the key and value
    }
    return str; // keep the string for the next loop
  }, "" /* <--- this empty string is the start value for our reduce operation */);
}

function getProperties(grade) {
  // if grade not null, and grade.properties not null, use keyValString(grade.properties) else use "No properties on grade."
  return (grade && grade.properties && keyValString(grade.properties)) || "No properties on grade."; // to instead return null, just replace the string with null
}

console.log( getProperties(grade1) );
console.log( getProperties(grade2) );
console.log( getProperties(grade3) );
console.log( getProperties(grade4) );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%} /* format the console output */
```

Comment: Hi sorry I just said i tried with a function and no luck, okay i tried that but ill explain what. i need exactly: if the grade has any property then display the name of that property and the value, a grade can have many or no properties if that makes sense so through every grade object in grades I need to extract properties and display them they can be like extra, weight, size, shape, anything really but single values so it's an input field so extra is a string of some description or size would be 150cm2 or something along the lines if that makes sense sorry I'm confused at it myself tbh

Comment: so the end return value would be for example Size: 20, Extra: This is important, Shape: Triangle, WeightMin: 4cm, or so from all the keys and values from the properties of  the grade object i have it in a for loop on the front end so i just need 1 grade properties to go through them and display the key and value

Comment: if that makes sense sorry @LaytonGB

Comment: That makes sense, I will edit my answer when I have time and comment to let you know it's done.

Comment: I have updated my code, I hope this is what you're after.

Comment: works like a charm thanks so much! Thank you for all the code comments as well!